# How to query a list with a given amount of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

I am a SQL beginner, I love this language and want to learn more about it. Now I get a problem: I have a list including people and there are 12 people whose name begin with 'M'. How can I query 5 people having name beginning with 'M'?

Person(ID, Name)

Comment: `select top 5 ... where left(name, 1)='M'`

Comment: Firstname or surname or both?

Comment: what have you tried? have you searched for solutions? you can find thousands of results for this issue.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL - TOP X in FROM Subquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791415/tsql-top-x-in-from-subquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Person
WHERE Person.Name LIKE 'M%'
```